# Multiple where condition with like and OR (not AND)

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am querying CosmosDB though LINQ/Iqueryable.

I have a method that have an IEnumerable in input which can have a lot of elements.

The desired query is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%input1%' OR field1 LIKE '%input2%'
```

and so on, ciclying though every IEnumerable element.

```
IEnumerable<string> filterElements = GetFiltersExample();

        IQueryable<ResultObject> theQuery = AzureDocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ResultObject>(
               collectionUri, queryOptions);

        if (filterElements.Count() > 0)
            foreach (string filterElement in filterElements)
            {
                theQuery = theQuery.Where(doc => doc.id.Contains(filterElement));
            }
```

But it generates this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (CONTAINS(field, 'input1') AND CONTAINS(field, 'input2'))
```

Which should work if LINQ wouldn't put them automatically in AND condition (and since there might be result without that string inside it returns empty because it doesn't match the condition).

How to do that in OR condition instead of AND?

I've tried with [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) but it didn't work, because it throws an exception about being unable to launch the Invoke method.

This is what I did:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ReturnObj>();
        if (elements.Count() > 0)
            foreach (string element in elements)
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(elem => elem.id.Contains(element));
            }
```

I've tried with various Contains even with using the string list to scan the query elements like [THIS](https://docs.telerik.com/data-access/feature-reference/api/linq-guide/data-access-tasks-querying-model-contains-containsExtended)

Linq persist in concatenating all the conditions with AND, so it will NEVER match multiple results unless you manually create the LINQ Query like this:

```
.Where(condition1 || condition2 || condition3.....)
```

How you can do this? It's incredible and I'm quite surprised in a negative manner of such a lack of functionality

Comment: `Or()` creates a bitwise or expression. `OrElse` is the conditional or you are probably looking for. `predicate.Or` will generate a `|` which `OrElse` a `||`

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/b33699418a8350b895ba28a1c6cb3f9aae03bbd5/Cosmonaut/Extensions/ExpressionExtensions.cs#L8) how I did something similar for `AndAlso` which is the conditional And

Comment: How do you inject this predicate into query? Can you show it?

Comment: It's in the link i shared. The AndAlso accepts a left and a right expression and it returns the result. Right is your current and left is the new one you're injecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it old style, using string concat, as I have this query only once in the project, I didn't wanted to use extenal libraries:

```
         StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * From TheCollection WHERE ");
        if (idsToCheck.Count() > 0)
            foreach (string idGuid in idsToCheck)
            {
                query.Append($" CONTAINS(TheCollection.id, '{idGuid}') OR ");
            }
        string builtQuery = query.ToString();
        builtQuery = builtQuery.Substring(0, builtQuery.Length - 4);

        IQueryable<ResultObject> Query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<ResultObject>(
               collectionUri, queryOptions);

        return Query.ToList();
```

And worked just fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) you can use `AsExpandable` on `IQueryable` so that all the invocations of expressions would be expanded to use the actual body of expression instead of `Invoke(element)`. For example if you have expression like this:

```
Expresssion<Func<int, bool>> expr = n => n == 1;
```

And some query like this:

```
var query = (EnumerableQuery<bool>)new[] { 1 }.AsQueryable().Select(n => d.Invoke(n))
```

The expression tree itself will contain the `Invoke` method which is not supported with this LINQ provider. But when you use `AxExpandable`:

```
var expQuery = (ExpandableQuery<bool>)new[] { 1 }.AsQueryable().AsExpandable().Select(n => d.Invoke(n))
```

The expression tree will contain the body `n => n == 1` without the `Invoke` method.

So in your case:

```
IQueryable<ResultObject> theQuery = AzureDocumentClient
    .CreateDocumentQuery<ResultObject>(collectionUri, queryOptions)
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(e => predicate.Invoke(e);
```

Should do the trick.

Alternatively if it's possible you can use the expression without `Invoke`:

```
.Where(predicate)
```

So there is no need for `AsExpandable`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather use a more common (and ugly) way than using an external library to only do a single query in the whole project.

I'll look forward to learn what you explained though

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you have found a workaround by using a query string instead. I just have a few comments on the behavior you've observed.

- In your first attempt, when you build the query by appending multiple Where clause, semantically, it means combining the filters or Intersecting the results. That is why AND is used instead of OR.

  - It'possible to use multiple where and then Union the results but that is far less efficient than using the combined query string.
- The PredicateBuilder complains about 'Invoke' being not supported. This is because the following reason. In a DocumentQuery LinQ expression, the Where() call would normally be translated into a WHERE clause in a Cosmos DB query string before being sent and executed in the Cosmos DB backend. If there is a non-standard function call, this function needs to be serialized. Unfortunately, it's not trivial to serialize any functions because of how cumbersome a function can get. That includes PredicateBuilder or a custom function you may have. However, Cosmos DB does have an alternative for this, and it is User-defined Functions (UDFs). (UDFs) can be use to executed a custom function in Cosmos DB back end.
- To use UDFs in this case, you can create a UDF with the body of the corresponding OR function and then use it in the Where() call. Some examples can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solved it by using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and the following extension method:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> items, Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> expression)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> comparison = p => expression.Invoke(p, item);
            predicate = predicate.Or(comparison.Expand());
        }

        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

With this approach you could write something like this:

```
// Create "connection" to Cosmos database
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient("AccountEndpoint=https://test.local/;AccountKey=Rm9vQmFy;");
var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase("database");
var container = database.GetContainer("container");

// Create some example existing data
var someExistingItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => new Item { Id = $"Item {i}" }).ToList();

// Prepare LINQ base query
var baseQuery = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Item>()
    // with maybe other desired methods to use
    .Where(item => item.PartitionKey == "somePartitionKey");

// Apply "magic" method to OR existing items by a dynamic criteria defined as lambda.
var query = baseQuery.WhereAny(someExistingItems, (x, y) => x.Id == y.Id);

// Print resulting query to console
var definition = query.ToQueryDefinition();
Console.WriteLine(definition.QueryText);
```

And the outcoming query would be:

> SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE ((root["PartitionKey"] = "somePartitionKey") AND (((root["Id"] = "Item 1") OR (root["Id"] = "Item 2")) OR (root["Id"] = "Item 3")))